# Single word for "in connection with"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to express "in connection with"? Example:

> He experiences many troubles [in connection with] this problem.

Comment: "regarding" would be an option, I suppose?

Comment: More like "related to", "due to", or "because of".

Comment: Maybe you could reword: *This problem causes him many troubles.*

Comment: @canpolat - and may be "concerning" too.

Answer (score 2):

He experiences many troubles **regarding** this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about grammar as a set of rules that help to convey understanding, then I must ask "why would you want to use a single word?"

The specific choice of words conveys specific meaning, and there may be several, different possible meanings e.g. "in direct consequence of this problem", or "while worrying about this problem", or even "while solving this problem".

Brevity does not equate to clarity: your meaning may be clear in your head, but don't assume that the reader knows what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for here is *associated*.

Answer (score 0):

Apropos?
He experiences many troubles apropos this problem.